# jupyterthemes jt command not found

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have installed jupyterthemes by `pip install --upgrade jupyterthemes` under Windows7. But when I type in cmd `jt -l`,it turns out `jt:command not found`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can do: `!jt -l`
To change the theme: `!jt -t 'themes name'` and reload

Answer (score 0):

Exit() python or ipython interpreter and try again e.g on PC using Anaconda prompt: `(base) C:\Users\YourAccount>jt -l` that should work if the themes pack was installed. That is what worked for me when I encountered this issue.